# Not able to access internal hosted website from within office env

Tags: dns

Not able to access internal hosted website from within office env.

Moving to new DNS Server 
Setup =
OS W2k19 (Domain controller/DSN server)
domain testthisisfake.fake
IP 10.1.60.30
forward zones contain:
10.1.60.30 by default (via windows configuration)
added:
10.1.60.18 (internal webhost)

Webhost
domain = testthisisfake.fake
IP 10.1.60.18

From in office when we type testthisisfake.fake in browser name cannot resolve.

nslookup shows 2 addresses which is part of issue (not sure how to fix since both are technically correct)

nslookup testthisisfake.fake
name: testthisisfake.fake
Addresses:
10.1.60.30
10.1.60.18

Removing DNS entry for 10.1.60.30 still does not resolve.

Since both the DC and the webhost use same "domain name" how do we then separate out traffic? I tried to add a CNAME (Alias) but windows barks at me and I cannot save.

Comment: Wouldn't the simple answer be to have `testthisisfake.fake` for the DC and e.g. `prefix.testthisisfake.fake` for the website? If I am not misunderstanding, you might also be able to set up IIS on `10.1.60.30` to forward `testthisisfake.fake` to `10.1.60.18`, but this isn't a recommended solution.

Comment: It's always DNS.

Comment: @music2myear , yep....added a www.testthisisfake.fake

Comment: @Anaksunaman  - added www prefix - works

Comment: @pthfndr2007 Glad to hear you got it working.